# JQuery dialog Not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the below jquery code its working on web but not on mobile

```js
function jsPopup(divID , msg, title, height ,width  ){
NWF$('#'+ divID +'').html("");
NWF$('#'+ divID +'').html(msg);
NWF$('#'+ divID +'').dialog({
                        title : "" + title + "" ,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                         },
                        minHeight: 104,
                        height: height ,
                        width: width  
});
                       
                       
NWF$('#'+ divID +'').dialog("open");                    

}
```

I calling the function using the below code

```js
jsPopup("divPopupBox" ,varMsg  , "Customer Information", 600 , 1000);
```

any idea or solution please help

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `width` and `height` to be a percentage like '80%', '80%'. Other than that post your html structure and css as well.

Comment: hello Noel, i try it but not working